# Xcode/Swift I want to add a Label live in the App with a button

Tags: ios, swift

I want to write an app for my iPhone and I want to add a "button" through that I can add a preconfigured label (configured in the code) to the app. How can I do that?

Comment: `let label = UILabel(); label.text = "Text", view.addSubview(label)`

Comment: Please add more detail. How is the button setup? Where should the new label be put? What have you tried? Answering these questions will help you get the answer you are looking for.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sorry for misunderstanding the first time. Assuming that you have your button created in the storyboard and linked in your code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var myButton: UIButton!

@IBAction func myButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    // Create the label with its dimensions
    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 21))
    // Set the label center point
    label.center = CGPoint(x: 160, y: 285)
    // Align the text to the center of the label
    label.textAlignment = .center
    // Set the label text
    label.text = "New label!"
    // Add the label to the main view
    self.view.addSubview(label)
}
```

You should modify the last line to add the label exactly in the view that you want.

Comment: Perfect Thanks! Thats what i needed! 
Just a few Questions.. 
1: For what do i need the first "line" with IBOutlet weark var.. ? 
2: Can i also delete this created label with a Button? 
3: Can i change the Label Text with an INPUT Text from the USER? 

I dont want to steal your time.. Maybe u know some good Tutorials on the WEB where i can find my answers or could you explain it?

Comment: When you create the button using the storyboard you need to link it to your code. To do it you can follow this steps: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/ConnectTheUIToCode.html

Comment: To delete the label you can use: `label.removeFromSuperview()`. If you create a TextField called field and link it to the code you can read the text that the user has wrote and assign it to the label with: `label.text = field.text`. Hope it helps. The tutorials from developer.apple.com are quite good to start from.

Comment: Just a basic Question. How does the second button with label.remove.. know that i mean exactly this label?